# Issue with rollup summary apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, error, roll-up-summary

I have the below code, but am getting the following error: "Didn't understand relationship 'Loan__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

```
 trigger TotalNetBankCommitment on Loan__c (after insert, after delete, after undelete, after update) {
    List<id> loanIdList = new List<id>();
    //if object is inserted/created or undelete
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete) {
        For(Loan__c loan1: Trigger.new) {
            loanIdList.add(loan1.Id);
        }
    }
    //if object is deleted
    if(Trigger.isDelete) {
        For(Loan__c loan1: Trigger.old) {
            loanIdList.add(loan1.Id);
        }
    }
    //if object is updated
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        For(Loan__c loan1: Trigger.new) {
            loanIdList.add(loan1.Id);
        }
    }

    List<Deal__c> dealUpdateList = new List<Deal__c>();
    For(Deal__c deal : [SELECT total_Net_Bank_Commitment__c, (SELECT Id FROM Loan__r) 
                                 FROM Deal__c
                                 WHERE isDeleted = false
                           AND id =: loanIdList]) {
            deal.otal_Net_Bank_Commitment__c = deal.Collateral__r.size();
          dealUpdateList.add(deal);   
    }
    try{
        update dealUpdateList;
        System.debug(dealUpdateList);
    }Catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Exception :'+e.getMessage());
    }                           
}
```

Does anyone have any Ideas why I would be getting this error?  When I run the exact same query in the query editor without the part in parenthesis it returns what I need.

Comment: The subquery in a parent-child subquery usually uses the plural of the object name. Try `Loans__r` instead.

Comment: @DerekF i'm assuming for something such as `Deposit_Fee__r` it would be the same, just `Deposit_Fees__r` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the API Name of any child relationship programmatically:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Parent__c.getChildRelationships())
{
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == Child__c.sObjectType)
    {
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
    }
}
```

For a lookup relationship from an object named `Loan__c`, you might expect this script to output `Loans__r`, but it wouldn't be surprising to see a different value. Whatever the script yields, that's what you would put in place of `Loan__r`, for example:

```
(SELECT Id FROM Loans__r)
```